# When to use template literals rather than evaluated JSX

Tags: reactjs

I'm working through a react beginner on-line course.
The instructor shows the first line of code and it works.
with the backtick etc.

But the second example works fine too and is easier to type and read.

Does it matter? When would the first example be preferred? 
Are their things the second example can't do that the first example can do?

```
return (
  <h1>Hello {`${firstName} ${lastName}`}!</h1>
)
```

But I noticed that this next line of code works just as well and is simpler to type and read.

```
return (
  <h1>Hello {firstName} {lastName}!</h1>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to build complex strings with characters/values not stored in variables, template literal might be the way to go.

Example: `` `${lastName}, ${firstName}` ``

I know that's not a "complex" example, and could be accomplished just as easily the other way, but you could imagine having to do this for much more complex scenarios.

You could also save that as it's own variable in case you need to reuse it.

`` const fullName = `${lastName}, ${firstName}` ``

And then all you would need later is just `{fullName}` without the template literal.

Answer (score 0):

Template literals (with backticks and `$`s) are a generic way to build strings in ES6, whereas the curly brackets alone are for evaluating Javascript specifically in JSX. If you're rendering Javascript in JSX and you don't need backticks and `$`s, then don't use them.